# Understanding Bayesian Online Change Point Detection (BOCPD)

Tags: probability, algorithms

This in reference to the paper by Ryan Adams and David Mackay linked [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.3742.pdf)

I am having problems understanding the paper fully. Are there any good sources to search for and understand the paper as well as involved models like conjugate exponential models. I have currently tried googling and reading from the following links, but much of the paper remains unclear.

1. [Gaussian process for time series modelling](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~sjrob/Pubs/philTransA_2012.pdf)
2. [Reading Documents for Bayesian Online Change Point Detection](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D15-1184)

Answer (score 3):

I wrote some [personal notes](https://jeremy9959.github.io/Blog/bayesian-online-changepoint-fixed/) on this paper.  Perhaps you will find them useful.

Comment: Hi, the notes are helpful indeed. However, in my case, I discovered that I was lacking background knowledge on Bayesian processes. So to anyone else who has problems understanding, it might be helpful to read up on basics.